# by using parcelable,trying to add an arraylist into another arraylist,getting error "the method add is not applicable for the arguments"

Tags: java, android

I have in one activity (firstactivity):

```
ArrayList <MyDouble> myfinals=new ArrayList <MyDouble>();
...
i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("myfinals",myfinals);
...
 public static class MyDouble implements Parcelable {
            Double al;


            public MyDouble(Parcel source){
                al = source.readDouble();
            }

            public MyDouble(Double val){
                al = val;
            }

            @Override
            public int describeContents() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return this.hashCode();
            }

            @Override
            public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dest.writeDouble(al);

            }

            public Double getValueDouble(){
                return this.al;
            }
            public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyDouble> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyDouble>() {

                @Override
                public MyDouble createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return new MyDouble(source);
                }

                @Override
                public MyDouble[] newArray(int size) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return new MyDouble[size];
                }
            };

        }
```

and in the other activity:

```
ArrayList <MyDouble> myfinals=new ArrayList <MyDouble>();
ArrayList<Double> y =new ArrayList<Double>();
...
 for (int i=0;i<=100;i++){
          y.add(myfinals.get(i)); 

       }
```

I am trying to add 'myfinals' to y
 but it gives me error "the method add is not applicable for the arguments 'firstactivity.MyDouble".

Comment: why should it? MyDouble doesn't inherit directly or non directly from Double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work:

```
for (int i=0;i<=100;i++){
    y.add(myfinals.get(i).getValueDouble()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Double and MyDouble are not the same object. The ArrayList y is expecting a Double object and you are trying to add a MyDouble object to it instead.